# I am creating a react app where I use vite, tailwind and shadcn ui and get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, shadcnui

I get an error in my react app; I am creating a react app where I use vite tailwind and shadcn ui

> [plugin:vite:css] [postcss] C:/Users/DENZEN Computer/OneDrive/Documents/React-30-Days-Challenge/SastaInsta/src/globals.css:3:1: The `bg-dark-1` class does not exist. If `bg-dark-1` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

This error mentions that `bg-dark-1` is not a class but it is a class.

My global CSS file:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  * {
    @apply box-border list-none p-0 m-0 scroll-smooth;
  }

  body {
    @apply bg-dark-1 text-white min-h-screen font-inter;
  }
}

@layer utilities {
  /* TYPOGRAPHY */
  .h1-bold {
    @apply text-[36px] font-bold leading-[140%] tracking-tighter;
  }

  .h1-semibold {
    @apply text-[36px] font-semibold leading-[140%] tracking-tighter;
  }

  .h2-bold {
    @apply text-[30px] font-bold leading-[140%] tracking-tighter;
  }

  .h3-bold {
    @apply text-[24px] font-bold leading-[140%] tracking-tighter;
  }

  .base-semibold {
    @apply text-[16px] font-semibold leading-[140%] tracking-tighter;
  }

  .base-medium {
    @apply text-[16px] font-medium leading-[140%];
  }

  .base-regular {
    @apply text-[16px] font-normal leading-[140%];
  }

  .body-bold {
    @apply text-[18px] font-bold leading-[140%];
  }

  .body-medium {
    @apply text-[18px] font-medium leading-[140%];
  }

  .small-semibold {
    @apply text-[14px] font-semibold leading-[140%] tracking-tighter;
  }

  .small-medium {
    @apply text-[14px] font-medium leading-[140%];
  }

  .small-regular {
    @apply text-[14px] font-normal leading-[140%];
  }

  .subtle-semibold {
    @apply text-[12px] font-semibold leading-[140%];
  }

  .tiny-medium {
    @apply text-[10px] font-medium leading-[140%];
  }

  /* UTILITIES */
  .invert-white {
    @apply invert brightness-0 transition;
  }

  .flex-center {
    @apply flex justify-center items-center;
  }

  .flex-between {
    @apply flex justify-between items-center;
  }

  .flex-start {
    @apply flex justify-start items-center;
  }

  .custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }

  .custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #09090a;
  }

  .custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #5c5c7b;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }

  .custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #7878a3;
  }

  .common-container {
    @apply flex flex-col flex-1 items-center gap-10 overflow-scroll py-10 px-5 md:px-8 lg:p-14 custom-scrollbar;
  }

  /* All Users */
  .user-container {
    @apply max-w-5xl flex flex-col items-start w-full gap-6 md:gap-9;
  }

  .user-grid {
    @apply w-full grid grid-cols-1 xs:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-7 max-w-5xl;
  }

  /* Explore */
  .explore-container {
    @apply flex flex-col flex-1 items-center overflow-scroll py-10 px-5 md:p-14 custom-scrollbar;
  }

  .explore-inner_container {
    @apply max-w-5xl flex flex-col items-center w-full gap-6 md:gap-9;
  }

  .explore-search {
    @apply h-12 bg-dark-4 border-none placeholder:text-light-4 focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-offset-0 ring-offset-0 !important;
  }

  /* Home */
  .home-container {
    @apply flex flex-col flex-1 items-center gap-10 overflow-scroll py-10 px-5 md:px-8 lg:p-14 custom-scrollbar;
  }

  .home-posts {
    @apply max-w-screen-sm flex flex-col items-center w-full gap-6 md:gap-9;
  }

  .home-creators {
    @apply hidden xl:flex flex-col w-72 2xl:w-465 px-6 py-10 gap-10  overflow-scroll custom-scrollbar;
  }

  /* Post Details */
  .post_details-container {
    @apply flex flex-col flex-1 gap-10 overflow-scroll py-10 px-5 md:p-14 custom-scrollbar items-center;
  }

  .post_details-card {
    @apply bg-dark-2 w-full max-w-5xl rounded-[30px] flex-col flex xl:flex-row border border-dark-4 xl:rounded-l-[24px];
  }

  .post_details-img {
    @apply h-80 lg:h-[480px] xl:w-[48%] rounded-t-[30px] xl:rounded-l-[24px] xl:rounded-tr-none object-cover p-5 bg-dark-1;
  }

  .post_details-info {
    @apply bg-dark-2 flex flex-col gap-5 lg:gap-7 flex-1 items-start p-8 rounded-[30px];
  }

  .post_details-delete_btn {
    @apply p-0 flex gap-3 hover:bg-transparent hover:text-light-1  text-light-1 small-medium lg:base-medium;
  }

  /* Profile */
  .profile-container {
    @apply flex flex-col items-center flex-1 gap-10 overflow-scroll py-10 px-5 md:p-14 custom-scrollbar;
  }

  .profile-inner_container {
    @apply flex items-center md:mb-8 xl:items-start gap-8 flex-col xl:flex-row relative max-w-5xl w-full;
  }

  .profile-tab {
    @apply flex-center gap-3 py-4 w-48 bg-dark-2  transition flex-1 xl:flex-initial;
  }

  /* Saved */
  .saved-container {
    @apply flex flex-col flex-1 items-center gap-10 overflow-scroll py-10 px-5 md:p-14 custom-scrollbar;
  }

  /* Bottom bar */
  .bottom-bar {
    @apply z-50 flex-between w-full sticky bottom-0 rounded-t-[20px] bg-dark-2 px-5 py-4 md:hidden;
  }

  /* File uploader */
  .file_uploader-img {
    @apply h-80 lg:h-[480px] w-full rounded-[24px] object-cover object-top;
  }

  .file_uploader-label {
    @apply text-light-4 text-center small-regular w-full p-4 border-t border-t-dark-4;
  }

  .file_uploader-box {
    @apply flex-center flex-col p-7 h-80 lg:h-[612px];
  }

  /* Grid Post List */
  .grid-container {
    @apply w-full grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-7 max-w-5xl;
  }

  .grid-post_link {
    @apply flex rounded-[24px] border border-dark-4 overflow-hidden cursor-pointer w-full h-full;
  }

  .grid-post_user {
    @apply absolute bottom-0 p-5 flex-between w-full bg-gradient-to-t from-dark-3 to-transparent rounded-b-[24px] gap-2;
  }

  /* Left sidebar */
  .leftsidebar {
    @apply hidden md:flex px-6 py-10 flex-col justify-between min-w-[270px] bg-dark-2;
  }

  .leftsidebar-link {
    @apply rounded-lg base-medium hover:bg-primary-500 transition;
  }

  /* Post Card */
  .post-card {
    @apply bg-dark-2 rounded-3xl border border-dark-4 p-5 lg:p-7 w-full max-w-screen-sm;
  }

  .post-card_img {
    @apply h-64 xs:h-[400px] lg:h-[450px] w-full rounded-[24px] object-cover mb-5;
  }

  /* Topbar */
  .topbar {
    @apply sticky top-0 z-50 md:hidden bg-dark-2 w-full;
  }

  /* User card */
  .user-card {
    @apply flex-center flex-col gap-4 border border-dark-4 rounded-[20px] px-5 py-8;
  }
}

@layer components {
  /* SHADCN COMPONENTS */
  /* Form */
  .shad-form_label {
    @apply text-white !important;
  }

  .shad-form_message {
    @apply text-red !important;
  }

  .shad-input {
    @apply h-12 bg-dark-4 border-none placeholder:text-light-4 focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-offset-1 ring-offset-light-3 !important;
  }

  .shad-textarea {
    @apply h-36 bg-dark-3 rounded-xl border-none focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-offset-1 ring-offset-light-3 !important;
  }

  /* Button */
  .shad-button_primary {
    @apply bg-primary-500 hover:bg-primary-500 text-light-1 flex gap-2 !important;
  }

  .shad-button_dark_4 {
    @apply h-12 bg-dark-4 px-5 text-light-1 flex gap-2 !important;
  }

  .shad-button_ghost {
    @apply flex gap-4 items-center justify-start hover:bg-transparent hover:text-white !important;
  }
}
```

I also check network tab and I see that the `globals.css` file is not load and error 500. I don't now what is the problem here

I want to set up the react app with vite, tailwind, and shadcn. I just install the button from shadcn and place it to my code

[Github Repo for full code](https://github.com/RafayMemon01/SastaInsta)

Comment: tailwind does not support `bg-dark`, is it custom? have a look at your `tailwind.config.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any references to `bg-dark-1` in your codebase or in the [tailwind documentation for background colors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color)

You could either use a predefined color (like `bg-slate-950` for a dark color), or add a custom one in your `tailwind.config.js` like so:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'dark': {
        1: '#07090c',
        2: '#25323f',
        // ...
      },
      // ...
    },
  },
}
```

(as explained further in tailwinds documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-custom-colors))

Comment: Try to specifically load the css file on that parent tsx component and see if it's loading then follow other approach. If its not loading than please share how you are loading the global.css in the child component.